# After taking video and in view section it is dark initially in Expo React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, expo, video-processing

Expo Managed React Native app: expo-av

I’m facing an issue in (my app built with react native expo)when taking and playing mp4 video on an IOS device. Image taking is fine but when start recording the video it’s showing as a black screen initially. In the video player, the video is stored and initially, it starts with a dark screen.

This is how I'm doing this:

```
in package.json:
"expo": ">=44.0.0-* <45.0.0",
"expo-av": "~10.2.0",
"expo-camera": "~12.1.0",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
```

```
import { Video, Audio } from "expo-av";
```

```
recordVideo = async () => {
   this.setState({ recording: true });
    if (this.cameraRef.current) {
      try {const timerInterval = setInterval(this.timeCounter, 1000);
           const { uri, codec = "MPEG" } = await 
       this.cameraRef.current.recordAsync({ maxDuration:this.state.videoDuration, codec: "mp4", quality:Camera.Constants.VideoQuality["4:3"]});
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      if (uri) {this.setState({ codec: codec });
   ... ... ...

 uploadVideo = async () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) {
      const { video_file } = JSON.parse(cameraData);
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("video_file", {
        name: this.getFileName(video_file),
        type: "video/mp4",
        uri:Platform.OS === "ios"
            ? video_file.replace("file://","")
            : video_file});
```

```
 <Video
   ref={this.video}
   source={{ uri: this.state.video_file }}
   shouldPlay={false}
   isMuted={true}
   resizeMode="cover"
   style={...}
   onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) =>this.setState({ setStatus: status })}/>
```